# Create tensor from n matrix of same size

Tags: matlab, matrix, multidimensional-array

I have a tensor stored in a file (each line of file is a matrix). In Matlab, I would like to read each line and then create a tensor of size 
number of lines * size(matrix at each line)
I am just wondering how to create a tensor from n matrix of same size?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `cat` instruction, for creating a tensor.
See http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cat.html

Example:
Suppose you have 3 matrices: R, G, and B, size 100x100 each.
Use: `RGB = cat(3, R, G, B);`
Now RGB is 100x100x3 tensor.

---

You can also use the following example:

```
%Initialize tensor with dimensions 3x4x5
T = zeros(3, 4, 5);

%Fill T with random 3x4 "plain" matrices:
for i = size(T, 5);
    A = rand(3, 4);
    T(:, :, i) = A;
end
```

---

Reading lines, converting to matrices using reshape, and place matrices in a tensor:

Suppose you have a text file were each line is a matrix.
Suppose you know matrix size, and number of matrices, and you want to create a tensor.

I created the following example file called rows.txt.

```
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2
3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3
4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4
5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5
```

The following code, initialize a 3x4x5 tensor, read a line, convert it to matrix, and insert to the tensor:

```
%Initialize tensor with dimensions 3x4x5
T = zeros(3, 4, 5);

f = fopen('rows.txt', 'r');

for i = 1:5
    R = fscanf(f, '%f\n', [1, 3*4]); %Read row from file into row vector R.
    A = reshape(R, [3, 4]); %Reshape R to 3x4 matrix.
    T(:, :, i) = A;
end

fclose(f);
```

Result:

```
T(:,:,1) =

     1     1     1     1
     1     1     1     1
     1     1     1     1


T(:,:,2) =

     2     2     2     2
     2     2     2     2
     2     2     2     2


T(:,:,3) =

     3     3     3     3
     3     3     3     3
     3     3     3     3


T(:,:,4) =

     4     4     4     4
     4     4     4     4
     4     4     4     4


T(:,:,5) =

     5     5     5     5
     5     5     5     5
     5     5     5     5
```

---

Another alternative:
Read entire text file into a vector, and use reshape to convert it to a tensor:

```
f = fopen('rows.txt', 'r');

%Read entire file into vector A.
A = fscanf(f, '%f');

%Reshape vector A into 3x4x5 tensor.
T = reshape(A, [3, 4, 5]);

fclose(f);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I have looked into cat, but I want my tensor to be of size 3 * 100 * 100.

Comment: Beside that I  have 50000 lines in the file, I should do this in a for loop.

Comment: Yes, I figured that out after reading the question again. I posted an alternative.

Comment: My last example, does't use a for loop. In case rows and columns dimensions do not match, use can permute to replace the order: `T = permute(T, [2, 1, 3]);`